# Running a python script on Nginx

Tags: nginx, python, uwsgi

This question might sound a bit odd to the people hanging out here, but i am just trying to start learning server side programming

Is it possible to run a python script directly in a Nginx server just by replacing

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.py; // instead of index.html index.htm
```

I tried running the same, but no result. All i was trying is to get the post data of the request and print it on a web-page.

I have searched a bit on google and found how to run python script using uWSGI and Ngnix - [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-uwsgi-and-nginx-to-serve-python-apps-on-ubuntu-14-04). I will defiantly go ahead and try this one, but it would be really nice, if some one can clear my doubt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a wsgi interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noap, you cant run python scripts by replacing the index.html. Doing so, you are serving a python file to the client/web-browser where he doesnt know how to interpret it.

As you correctly stated, you may use uWSGI in order to execute python scripts on your server.